# Path from js file to the root folder

Tags: javascript, php

I have one problem with a script. When I have the script code in **script tags** inside html file, it works but when I transfer the code to the .js file, stops working.

This is a part of the script from js file:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        type: "post",
        data: values,
        success: function(data){
            $("#result").html(data);
            return data;
        }
```

Well, when it is in the folder of js file I change the url to:

- url: "../test.php"

  and I also tried
- url: "/includes/test.php"

  none works. What I am missing here?

Comment: if you are working on a website than give that link!!! or give complete code also of your html or php...

Comment: Did you included your js file after moving the script.?

Comment: Yes, because i have some other scripts inside. The path to the file from html is OK.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change path of url parameters.

```
url: "test.php"
```

Instead of this you have to give path from your web directory from www like:

```
url: "/FOLDER_NAME/test.php".
```

Where `/FOLDER_NAME` is name of folder in WWW folder till *test.php*

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

use $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] to get the base url.

```
 url: "$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/FOLDER_NAME/test.php'"
```